# JUCE - Member Function Not Viable: 'this' Argument Has Type const

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, constants, juce

I'm trying to create a tabbed window by reading from a ValueTree in JUCE.

I'm using the below code to set the corresponding tab's root item to a child of the tree (full code available [here](https://gist.github.com/J-Bledsoe/c83ddfa9e9f9c3a03c57bbb8626c9a94)). However, I get the error:

> "Member function 'getValueTree' not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const GlobalValueTree', but function is not marked const".

I am using an object as the tree returned by `getValueTree()` or the function itself are non-static.

```
AccelerometerPage (const DataSelectorWindow& w)
{
    tree.setRootItem (rootItem = new const OscValueTreeItem
    (w.valueTree.getValueTree()->getChildWithName ("AccData")));
}
```

Can somebody point me in the right direction as to why this is incorrect and how to go about fixing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I get the error "Member function 'getValueTree' not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const GlobalValueTree', but function is not marked const"

This is because `w` is `const` but the method `getValueTree` can work only on non-const `DataSelectorWindow` objects.

If the DataSelectorWindow object was written by you, and you think that `getValueTree()` should be allowed to be called on `const` objects, change its prototype to:

```
<return-value> getValueTree(<params>) const {
    ...
}
```

If the DataSelectorWindow object was written by someone else, your 
`AccelerometerPage` c'tor should receive a non-const `DataSelectorWindow&`, like this:

```
AccelerometerPage (DataSelectorWindow& w) {
    ...
}
```